# Is it safe to use select * in views?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I've grown quite fond of the usefulness of `CREATE VIEW`. It for instance allows me to have global and specific values through `COALESCE(post.publish, profile.publish)` so that if `publish` is `NULL`, the global value gets fetched instead.

The part I'm a bit curious about from both perfomance and logical perspective, is how I should use this alongside the existing table. Lets say I have a  table:

```
CREATE TABLE post (
    id INT,
    profile_id INT,
    name VARCHAR,
    publish ENUM('TRUE', 'FALSE') NULL
)
```

Would a `CREATE VIEW` be best to run like:

```
CREATE VIEW post_info AS
SELECT post.*, COALESCE(post.publish, profile.publish) AS publish
FROM post
INNER JOIN profile
ON post.profile_id = profile.id
```

And only use `post_info` in `SELECT` cases, or:

```
CREATE VIEW post_info AS
SELECT post.id, COALESCE(post.publish, profile.publish) AS publish
FROM post
INNER JOIN profile
ON post.profile_id = profile.id
```

And `JOIN` `post_info` with `post` in `SELECT` when extra values are needed?

Please share your insights and thoughs regarding this. I would like to hear your input to positives and drawbacks of each solution. Can also be one I haven't mentioned.

Comment: `SELECT *` is never good.

Comment: I know that I usually like to avoid `*`. However I feel this to be a special case where you would complete the table with more columns.

Comment: `publish ENUM('TRUE', 'FALSE') NULL`?! Eeek ! Why not `publish BOOLEAN NULL` ?

Comment: I found it easier to get a good overview of my tables rather than having a lot of integers in more columns. Maybe not the best reason, but just got used to it.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you will use the views. It should be worth mentioning that there are two methods MySQL can process a query that refers to a view, and the method used depends on the view declaration's `ALGORITHM` clause.

For the lack of a better phrasing, I will reproduce [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html):

> For `[ALGORITHM =] MERGE`, the text of a statement that refers to the view and the
>   view definition are merged such that parts of the view definition
>   replace corresponding parts of the statement.
>
> For `TEMPTABLE`, the results from the view are retrieved into a
>   temporary table, which then is used to execute the statement.
>
> For `UNDEFINED`, MySQL chooses which algorithm to use.

The `MERGE` algorithm usually allows faster processing of the final query, however there are many cases where MySQL is unable to use it (see the linked manual page for more details).

So the answer is: if your view is not defined with `ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE` **and** if the wrapping query does not prevent the use of the `MERGE` algorithm, the version with `SELECT *`, and without an extra `JOIN`, is better.

Otherwise, if `MERGE` is not used, the second solution could be better.

As a side note, to adress the use case you mention, a better option would be to have your application layer fill the `post.publish` with the value in `profile.publish` at insertion time, and get rid of the `JOIN` as well as the view. Alternatively, the same effect can be achieved by placing a suitable trigger on the table.

Comment: If I want the global value to be able to affect it even after the post was created, filling in the value wouldn't be ideal for me. I need to grow wiser on those `ALGORITHM`s I think.

Comment: You would get much better results if you added a column like "`isDefaultValue BOOLEAN`. Then you can `UPDATE post SET publish = whatever_id WHERE isDefaultValue`. It makes the update a bit longer but the retreival much quicker, and I suppose the global value is *changed* less often than *read*. Besides, this is a concern of the application layer (a business rule), not something the database should worry about. But I stop being pedantic now :)